# Upload Image From react native expo to asp.net web api

Tags: c#, react-native, asp.net-web-api

I'm doing exactly I do in React JS I want to upload image on my server through react native expo app but I'm getting exception on my server code.

API is running perfectly in POSTMAN but not in App

My React Code

```
      const upload = () => {
    const data = new FormData();
    const headers = {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    };

    // data.append("file", {
    //   file: image,
    // });
console.log(image)
    data.append("file",image)
    // data.append('FileName',driverDetail.DriverName)
    // data.append('Id',4)

    console.log(data);
    axios
      .post("http://203.101.163.181:8554/api/Admin/SaveImage", data, headers)
      .then((result) => console.log(result.data))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
  };
```

Here Is my ASP.NET API Code

```
   public HttpResponseMessage SaveFile()
    {
        try
        {
            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            var postedfiles = httpRequest.Files[0];
            var fileName = postedfiles.FileName;
            var physicalPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + fileName);
            postedfiles.SaveAs(physicalPath);

            UserRegistrationModel obj = new UserRegistrationModel();
            //if (obj.UpdateImage(httpRequest.Params.Get("FileName"), Convert.ToInt32(httpRequest.Params.Get("Id"))) == 1)
            //{
            //    return Request.CreateResponse("Success");
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    return Request.CreateResponse("Failed");
            //}

            return Request.CreateResponse("Success");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return Request.CreateResponse(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to send a file in a context? Try sending it via IFormFile

Comment: I'm not using asp.net core

Comment: issue resolve the problem is with axios

Answer (score 0):

Don't use axios for uploading files and images in React native use simple fetch function

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).